# How to import a user model profile to a papyrus project in omnet++?

Tags: uml, omnet++

I need to create a dataset for Multi-UAVs communication and for that, I need to perform simulation as to the best of my knowledge such type of dataset is not available. 
I am using Omnet++ for simulation purposes. I have created a papyrus project and then want to import a profile.larissa.uml to my project but it's not importing the profile.

Not much data is available related to profile.larissa.uml but I have found a video here is the link 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yE7yPy5D7M8&feature=youtu.be
but he imported the file and I am doing the same and unable to import the file.